# Access nested ListView TextBoxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, listview, nested

I am trying to get my nested ListView's (ListView within a ListView) textbox with Javascript. This is what I have set up in my ListViews:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LV_Tickets" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQL_Tickets" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" OnPreRender="LV_Tickets_PreRender" DataKeyNames="TicketNum">
<SelectedItemTemplate>
<asp:ListView ID="LV_TicketProd" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ChargeID" DataSourceID="SQL_TicketProducts" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" OnPreRender="LV_TicketProd_PreRender" OnItemInserted="LV_TicketProd_ItemInserted" OnItemInserting="LV_TicketProd_ItemInserting" OnItemUpdated="LV_TicketProd_ItemUpdated" OnItemUpdating="LV_TicketProd_ItemUpdating" OnItemCommand="LV_TicketProd_ItemCommand">
</ SelectedItemTemplate>
```

I am aware that to get `LV_Tickets` I can call `getElementByName`, but after that I am lost and cannot find any help on the subject. How should I go about this?

Comment: can you show id of `TextBox` Using FireBug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get the nestedlistview by id if you know id

```
var nestedlistview=document.getElementById("LV_TicketProd");
```

And if you do not know id of nestedlistview than you can get it by it's parent'd id

```
var listview=document.getElementById("LV_Tickets");
var nestedListView=listview.querySelector("#LV_TicketProd");
```

Comment: So how would I go about getting and setting the value of a textbox that is inside this listview?